# Deterministic Randomness Extractors

Tags: randomness

I have read in several papers it is well known that deterministically extracting even one bit from a weak source is impossible. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Not sure what exactly they have in mind for "weak source", but maybe this is answered by Vadhan's chapter on Extractors ([pdf](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/extractors.pdf)) in Prop 6.6, or the discussion after Lemma 6.8.

Comment: They mean a distribution with min-entropy $k$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intuitively, the situation is you'd like some deterministic extractor $E: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ that can take in $n$ bits sampled from a weak source and output one bit with probability close to $1/2$, say it outputs 0 with probability $1/2 \pm \epsilon$ and 1 with $1/2\pm\epsilon$.

Here's a weak argument that at the very least, such extractors $E$ can't exist if we don't put any restrictions on the input distribution other than it has 'enough' min-entropy. Suppose $E$ is such a potential extractor. By flipping the output if necessary, we may assume without loss of generality that $|E^{-1}(0)|\ge|E^{-1}(1)|$; that is, $E^{-1}(0)$ is a set of $n$-bit strings of size at least $2^{n}/2$. Thus a random variable that samples uniformly from $E^{-1}(0)$ will have min-entropy at least $n - 1$, but the extractor will never give you any 'random' output other than 0.

Of course, if we tighten the restrictions on the input distribution (say, we assume all $n$ bits are IID) then we do have deterministic extractors that work. But as problem 6.6 in Salil Vadhan's survey of pseudorandomness shows, even weakening the IID assumption a little bit will cause deterministic extractors to fail, by a slight generalization of the same argument as I made above.

Comment: I think you mean "will have min-entropy $\geq n - 1$".

Comment: It's not precisely min-entropy $\ge n-1$ because the set could be smaller than $2^{n-1}$ by a constant fraction. So in this case, saying $\Omega(n-1)$ could be slightly misleading , even though it's equivalent to $\Omega(n)$

Comment: Of course, one can always look at both $E^{-1}(0)$ and $E^{-1}(1)$, and then sampling uniformly from the larger would always have min-entropy $\ge n-1$ as you suggest.

Comment: My comment was based on the previous edit. I thought you were trying to emphasize that the min-entropy is very close to $n$ (off by an additive constant), which is stronger than just saying it's $\Omega(n)$ (although the latter is true and still certainly makes your point).

Comment: I think I was a bit imprecise in my initial statement and that led to some confusion through the several edits